# Kendo Grid Search ParameterMap

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I am not able to get the following to call the web service function.  It has something to do with the ParameterMap since if I call a function that does not need parameters (Meditech_MeditechSearchResultsTEST) then I get results. I have logging set up on the Meditech_MeditechSearchResults web service function and can tell it never gets called.

```
        function GetQuery() {

            var SearchText;
            var URLLink;

            SearchText = document.getElementById('QueryID').value;
            var FilterSelected;
            FilterSelected = document.getElementById('ArchivedResultsSelect').value;
            URLLink = URL + 'Meditech_MeditechSearchResults';
            var CurrPage = 1;
            var Pagesize =10;

            try {

                if (SearchText != '') {
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                            attributes: {
                                "class": "SearchControls"
                            },
                            dataSource: {
                                pageSize:  Pagesize,
                                transport: {
                                    read: {
                                        url: URLLink,
                                        type: "GET",
                                        dataType: "jsonp",
                                    }
                                },
                                type: {
                                    data: "odata"
                                },
                                parameterMap: function (options) {
                                    var parameters = {

                                        Search: FormatJSONString(SearchText),
                                        FilterValue: FilterSelected,
                                        CurrentPage: CurrPage,
                                        PageSize: Pagesize
                                    }
                                    return parameters;
                                },

                            },
                            columns: [{
                                field: "View",
                                title: "",
                                width: "30px",
                                align: "center",
                                template: kendo.template($("#view-template").html())

                            },
                            {
                                field: "Results",
                                title: "Results",
                                width: "800px",
                                template: kendo.template($("#result-template").html())

                            },
                            {
                                field: "Rank",
                                title: "Rank",
                                width: "40px",

                            },
                            ],

                            height: 500,
                            width: 900,
                            scrollable: true,
                            pageable: {
                                refresh: true,
                                pageSizes: true,
                                buttonCount: 5
                            },
                            error: function(e) {
                                alert(e.errors);
                        },
                        });
                    });

                }
                else { alert('Please enter a search text.') }
            }
            catch(ex) {
                alert(ex.description);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [parameterMap](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap) option is part of the `transport` configuration. Try putting it there. Right now it is ignored.